# Django - mix two annotated values into one with a Case/When make the performance getting slow on many elements

Tags: python, django, case

In get_queryset function inside a viewset I buid a queryset that needs to list a big amount of "Course" but with annotating some counts of a children model "CoursePerson".

It could have like 10000 "Course" objects with in total ~5 millions of "CoursePerson" objects.

I would like to annotate "interact_count" by taking another annotated value depending of the Course type.
If I remove then "interact_count" annotation django + postgresql taking ~20-50ms to answer. But when I put back that annotation, it takes like 600-800ms.
I am pretty sure the Case/When is the cause of this latency. But I don't know how to do other way cause I need only one count. (And not 2)

I don't wanna do that with python because I would lose the ordering or pagination.

This part is the problem:
How can I do the same but more performantly ?

```
interact_count=Case(
  When(
    Q(type=models.Course.TypeChoices.PHISHING)
     | Q(type=models.Course.TypeChoices.SMS),
    then=course_person_open_subquery,
  ),
  default=course_person_extra_subquery,
 )
```

full queryset:

```
course_person_open_subquery = Subquery(
    CoursePerson.objects.filter(
        course_id=OuterRef('uid'),
        status__gte=models.CoursePerson.StatusChoices.OPEN
    )
    .annotate(count=Func(F('uid'), function="Count"))
    .values('count'),
    output_field=IntegerField()
)

course_person_extra_subquery = Subquery(
    CoursePerson.objects.filter(
        course_id=OuterRef('uid'),
        status__gt=models.CoursePerson.StatusChoices.OPEN
    )
    .annotate(count=Func(F('uid'), function="Count"))
    .values('count'),
    output_field=IntegerField()
)


return models.Course.objects.annotate(
    interact_count=Case(
        When(
            Q(type=models.Course.TypeChoices.PHISHING)
            | Q(type=models.Course.TypeChoices.SMS),
            then=course_person_open_subquery,
        ),
        default=course_person_extra_subquery,
    ),
).all()
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't say first, but I know why it's slow.
It's because there are also 3 others annotations that puts 3 more JOINs.
If I put the "interact_count" annotation alone (with my solution and with the @Clepsyd one). It's way faster.
**So my problem here is "only" because there are 4 JOINs**

here the other annotations that put 3 JOINs:

```
account_count=Count("accounts", distinct=True),
groups_count=Count("groups", distinct=True),
domain_name=F("domain__name"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use the `Count` function here, not subqueries. You can pass it `filter` kwargs to fine tune how you count the related models you're counting. Your Case/When + subqueries can be replaced by a more complex filter using Q objects passed to the Count function.

I think this should work:

```
phishing_and_sms_filter = Q(
    type__in=[
        models.Course.TypeChoices.PHISHING,
        models.Course.TypeChoices.SMS
    ],
    courseperson__status__gte=models.CoursePerson.StatusChoices.OPEN
)
default_filter = Q(
    courseperson__status__gt=models.CoursePerson.StatusChoices.OPEN
)

models.Course.objects.annotate(
    interact_count=Count(
        'courseperson',
        filter=Q(phishing_and_sms_filter | default_filter)
    )
).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the same results with your solution (so that's ok) but the performance are worst than my subqueries (weird). But will edit the first message because my "interact_count" annotation isn't the only in fault... I also have 3 others annotations that I didn't put in the original code that put 3 JOINs. and THAT is why it take way more time. Your solution alone (and mine) would be like 30-50ms so that's ok.